# Remove duplicate rows based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've a vista like this:

> ```
> Agenzia    Codice Nome
> Globmaster    012 NORTHWEST AIRLINES
> Globmaster    020 LUFTHANSA CARGO
> Globmaster    023 FEDERAL EXPRESS
> Globmaster    024 EUROPEAN AIR EXPRESS EAE
> Globmaster    988 ASIANA
> Globmaster    994 LINEAS AEREAS AZTECA
> Globmaster    995 B & H AIRLINES
> Globmaster    997 BIMAN
> Gabbiano  012 NORTHWEST AIRLINES
> Gabbiano  020 LUFTHANSA CARGO
> Gabbiano  023 FEDERAL EXPRESS
> Gabbiano  400 PALESTINIAN AIRLINES
> Gabbiano  406 UPS AIRLINES
> Gabbiano  407 AIR SENEGAL INTERNATIONAL
> ```

I need to modify the query so that it won't give duplicate codes (Codice) at the result:

```
SELECT     'Gabbiano' AS Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn, SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, 
                      FlCancellato, DataUltModifica, IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax, ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, 
                      PathCondGen
FROM         dbo.TVTV0000
UNION
SELECT     'Istantravel' AS Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn, SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, 
                      FlCancellato, DataUltModifica, IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax, ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, 
                      PathCondGen
FROM         IstanTravel.dbo.TVTV0000 AS Statistiche_1
UNION
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT 'Globmaster' AS Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn, SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, 
                      CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, FlCancellato, DataUltModifica, IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax, 
                      ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, PathCondGen
FROM         Globmaster.dbo.TVTV0000 AS Statistiche_2
ORDER BY Codice
```

I don't even know why I get that silly TOP (100) PERCENT anyway ;)

Edit:
It should return something like:

> ```
> Agenzia    Codice Nome
> Globmaster    012 NORTHWEST AIRLINES
> Globmaster    020 LUFTHANSA CARGO
> Globmaster    023 FEDERAL EXPRESS
> Globmaster    024 EUROPEAN AIR EXPRESS EAE
> Globmaster    988 ASIANA
> Globmaster    994 LINEAS AEREAS AZTECA
> Globmaster    995 B & H AIRLINES
> Globmaster    997 BIMAN
> Gabbiano  400 PALESTINIAN AIRLINES
> Gabbiano  406 UPS AIRLINES
> Gabbiano  407 AIR SENEGAL INTERNATIONAL
> ```

Comment: So, which one should we take>? globmaster gabbiano or istantravel

Comment: I doesn't matter which agency, the important is that only rows with non-duplicate codes are there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TOP 100 PERCENT` was used to be able to add `ORDER BY` to the view source (to avoid the final `ORDER BY`, which is simply stupid).

You must define a priority, which *Agenzia* should be listed first:

```
SELECT Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn,
       SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, FlCancellato, DataUltModifica,
       IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax,
       ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, PathCondGen
FROM
 ( SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY Codice
            ORDER BY priorty ) AS rn
   FROM
    (

      SELECT    1 AS priority, 'Gabbiano' AS Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn,
                SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, FlCancellato, DataUltModifica,
                IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax,
                ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, PathCondGen
      FROM dbo.TVTV0000
      UNION ALL -- probably more efficient than UNION
      SELECT    2 AS priority, 'Istantravel' AS Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn,
                SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, FlCancellato, DataUltModifica,
                IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax,
                ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, PathCondGen
      FROM IstanTravel.dbo.TVTV0000 AS Statistiche_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT     3 AS priority, 'Globmaster' AS Agenzia, Codice, Descrizione, FlBSP, MastroForn, CapocForn, ContoForn,
                SottocForn, CodIVANazAtt, CommNazAttiva, CommIntAttiva, FlCancellato, DataUltModifica,
                IDUtente, IDTerminale, CodAnagrafico, NoteDirPortAnd, NoteDirPortRit, ImpDirPortPax,
                ImpDirPortVei, GGScad, PathCondGen
      FROM Globmaster.dbo.TVTV0000 AS Statistiche_2
    ) AS dt
 ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Over is not supported by SQL Server 2005 :)

Comment: @Bass: Of course `ROW_NUMBER` is supported in SQL Server 2005. Based on your edit you just have to modify the `priority` accordingly.

Comment: @Bass: Does my answer work? If you don't have any preferred agency you can remove the `priority` and change `ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY Codice
            ORDER BY Codice)`

Comment: No priority needed :) i just need a duplicate free code list so i can use it to run a LOOKUP on powerpivot :)

Comment: However i can't use your answer since i'm on SQL Server 2005. What do you mean with change ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Codice ORDER BY Codice) ?

Comment: @Bass: SQL Server 2005 supports ROW_NUMBER: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Yay! I did it! However the OVER statement must NOT be entered from the designer :)

Comment: @Bass: *Any* more complex SQL must be entered manually, GUIs only cover the basic things :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT

```
   SELECT DISTINCT Codice FROM Globmaster.dbo.TVTV0000 AS Statistiche_2
ORDER BY Codice
```